# Drill down pie chart disappears

Tags: d3.js

I make a drill down pie chart and it works well.
You can see it [here](http://elevendesk.com/pie/index.html).

But there is an issue:

1) click a node then it shows its children (level 1) or level 0 nodes.
2) Move mouse to another position and move back to the new node which contains its original position, the node disappears.

I think there is problem in this code (gradientPie.js)

```
var paths = gPie.selectAll("path").data(pieChart(currData), function(d) {return d.data.cat;});
var texts = gPie.selectAll("text").data(pieChart(currData), function(d) {return d.data.cat;});
var lines = gPie.selectAll("line").data(pieChart(currData), function(d) {return d.data.cat;});

var arcs =  paths.enter().append("g").attr('class', 'slice');
arcs.append("path").attr("fill", function(d, i) { return "url(#gradient" + d.data.cat + ")"; })
    .transition().duration(1000).attrTween("d", tweenIn).each("end", function(){
      this._listenToEvents = true;
      gradPie.transitioning = false;
    })
    .attr("id", function(d, i){return 'p' + i;})
    .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });

arcs.append("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
    var c = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius * 1.4).innerRadius(radius).centroid(d);
    return "translate(" + (0 + c[0]) + "," + (0 + c[1]) + ")";
    })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("class", "text-main")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("fill", "#3f5763")
  .style("font", "bold 14px Helvetica")
  .text(function(d) {
    $("#" + d.data.domID + " p").html(d.data.percent + "%");
    return d.data.percent + "%";
  });

arcs.append("line").attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    var rAngle = ((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 - (Math.PI / 2)) * 180 / Math.PI;
    return "rotate(" + rAngle + ")translate(" + radius * 1.1 + ")";
  })
  .attr("class", "line-ticks")
  .attr('stroke-width', '1')
  .attr("x2", -0.5 * radius)
  .style("stroke", "#3f5763")
  .style("fill", "none");


// Mouse interaction handling
paths.on("click", function(d, i){
    if(this.childNodes[0]._listenToEvents && !gradPie.transitioning){
      // Reset inmediatelly
      d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      // Change level on click if no transition has started
      paths.each(function(){
         this.childNodes[0]._listenToEvents = false;
      });
      updateGraph(d.data.subfractions? d.data.cat : undefined);
    }
  })
.on("mouseover", function(d, i){

    // Mouseover effect if no transition has started
    if(this.childNodes[0]._listenToEvents && !gradPie.transitioning) {

      // Calculate angle bisector
      var ang = (d.endAngle + d.startAngle)/2;
      // Transformate to SVG space
      ang = (ang - (Math.PI / 2) ) * -1;

      // Calculate a 10% radius displacement
      var x = Math.cos(ang) * radius * 0.1;
      var y = Math.sin(ang) * radius * -0.1;

      d3.select(this).transition()
        .duration(250).attr("transform", function() {
            return "translate(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
        })
    }
  })
.on("mouseout", function(d){

  // Mouseout effect if no transition has started
  if(this.childNodes[0]._listenToEvents && !gradPie.transitioning){
    d3.select(this).transition()
      .duration(150).attr("transform", function() {
        return "translate(0,0)";
      });
  }
});



// Collapse sectors for the exit selection
  paths.exit().transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attrTween("d", tweenOut).remove();

  texts.exit().transition()
    .duration(100).remove();

  lines.exit().transition()
    .duration(100).remove();
```

Any help?

Comment: Looks like you fixed it, since I tried clicking on the pie pieces and it seems to transition back and forth between the zoomed in and zoomed out versions. And all the mouseover behavior appears to be what you want it to do.

Comment: No, the issue still remains. I think I didn't write correctly.
Please don't move mouse as soon as you click a node. Keep it position after new node is rendered in that position. After that move it.